# UITabBarViewController - Keep Storyboard Connections?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

Is it possible to keep the storyboard @IBOutlets if I am creating UITabBarItem's programmatically?

For example:

```
    let vc2 = BellTabVC()
    let icon2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
    vc2.tabBarItem = icon2
    self.viewControllers = [vc2]
```

However, this crashes on line,

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

when tableView is an @IBOutlet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash happens, because the programmatically created class is not connected to the storyboard anymore.

What you can do is load the storyboard controller in code **including** the implemented class with the outlets, like this:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourProfileViewController") as! YourProfileViewController
```

Then you can do with your controller what you want (loading it into another controller, changing it...).